# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un carrusel de varios elementos utilizando bootstrap con el menor código posible?

Tags: javascript, angular, slider

Estoy tratando de hacer un carrusel como se aprecia en esta imagen:

[image: carousel multi-item]

Mi código actual es este:

```js
<div class="container" id="contenedor-global">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"> <div> <span class="text-hot"> <b>HOT</b> </span> </div> </div> <div id="div-redondo" class="d-flex ml-2 align-items-center justify-content-center"> <div class="text-hot align-middle">  list </div> </div>
    </div>


<div *ngIf="inmuebles!=null; else espera">
  <div class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" id="multi_item">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i].id}}_{{inmuebles[i].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus "></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2" >Precio: {{inmuebles[i].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2">Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
                </div>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i+1].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+1].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+1].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+1].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+2].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+2].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+2].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i+3].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+3].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+3].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+3].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i+4].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+4].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+4].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+4].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i+5].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+5].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+5].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+5].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" (click)="anteriorInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" (click)="siguienteInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<ng-template #espera>Esperando datos...</ng-template>
</div>
```

El código es demasiado repetitivo, así que debe haber una manera de tener un solo contenedor y con javascript generar los demas o con bootstrap hacerlo de una manera mas facil, pero estoy empezando recientemente con angular y bootstrap y al menos en la documentación de bootstrap no encuentro algo parecido.

También tengo un modal que se muestra al hacer clic en cada botón (ver detalles) de los artículos.

Finalmente, lo que me gustaría mejorar es el código del Slider, en la documentación de Bootstrap veo que solo explican hacerlo con una sola imagen, también intenté usar NGX-BOOTSTRAP y no logré que funcionara aunque instalé todas las dependencias como Popper.js, javascript, JQuery y bootstrap.

¿Alguien sería tan amable de echarme una mano con el código u orientarme en como podria mejorarlo? Me sería de gran aydua.

Gracias por adelantado. ¡Saludos!

Comment: A priori, se me ocurre que podrías almacenar los datos que muestras en el carrusel en algun objeto y hacerte una plantilla con el código que se repite, en base a eso podrías iterar y lo tendrías

Comment: pero haciendolo así me ahorraría tener 6 contenedores para los ítems? podrias mostrarme un ejemplo de la creación de los contenedores?

Comment: En mi opinión lo que podrías hacer es utilizar **JavaScript** o **PHP** para meter tu código repetido en un ciclo _for_ o _while_ y solo cambiar tu variable para identificar las imágenes enlace y contenido el carrusel

Comment: @DonaldoManzano el ciclo que mencionas lo usaría para crear los contenedores (items) del slider?

Answer (score 0):

Sé que la pregunta hace referencia a cómo hacerlo con menos código, y no usando una librería, pero está yo la he utilizado en varias ocasiones y tiene muy buen soporte y es muy fácil de usar.
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Lo primero es importar la libreria a tu 
`ìndex.html`  (Asegurate que tengas la libreria guardada en la misma ruta  que pones en la referencia el link).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/> // Add the new slick-theme.css if you want the default styling 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
```

en tu archivo `index.html` agregamos el siguiente código.

```
<div class="your-class">  
    <div>your content</div>  
    <div>your content</div>  
    <div>your content</div>  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.your-class').slick(); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Y listo, ya tienes un slider muy con poco código.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], pues los aportes que son solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad